# disabling animation in Wpf

Tags: wpf, image

I am able to provide animation to an image button from below code.

```
this.RegisterName(image1.Name, image1);
DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
myDoubleAnimation.From = 1.0;
myDoubleAnimation.To = 0.0;
myDoubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.25));
myDoubleAnimation.AutoReverse = true;
myDoubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
myStoryboard.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation);
Storyboard.SetTargetName(myDoubleAnimation, image1.Name);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(myDoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(Image.OpacityProperty));
myStoryboard.Begin(this);
```

Now I need to stop the animation .

Below is the sample code.

```
TimeSpan? ts = new TimeSpan(0,0,2); 
DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
myDoubleAnimation.From = 1.0;
myDoubleAnimation.To = 0.0;
myDoubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
myStoryboard.BeginTime = ts; 
myDoubleAnimation.AutoReverse = true; 
myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
myStoryboard.Children.Remove(myDoubleAnimation); 
myStoryboard.Stop(this);
```

I am not able to stop the animation for image button.
Please guide me for above issues.

Regards,

Sachin K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you're stopping a `Storyboard` that wasn't started. You're creating an entirely new `Storyboard` in an attempt to stop the original, but that is nonsensical. Just keep a reference to the original and stop *it*.

Comment: Hi Kent,
I am new to Xaml(Wpf) technology.
I have removed initialization of mystoryboard.The above two are happenning on two button events.I have initialized mystoryboard well before both events. I have tried to keep common  reference.But still it doesnot stop.

Comment: Thanks Kent,I got the solution.I used this.
myStoryboard.Begin(this,true);